# How to get a heap dump from Kubernetes k8s pod?

Tags: java, kubernetes, memory-leaks, kubernetes-pod, heap-dump

Please provide a simple step by step guide to looking into java heap dump from a Kubernetes pod.

Answer (score 27):

1. Log in to the K8S and exec into the Pods where your java application is running.

```
kubectl exec -it herle-deployment-pod-5757d89d85-wrpc9 bash
```

2. get the process id (top command)
3. Create java heap dump

```
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=<file_name>.bin <process_id>
```

Example:

```
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=application_heap_dump.bin 1
```

4. Copy the heap dump from pod to your local machine.

```
kubectl cp <pod_name>:<heap_file> <your local destination directory>
```

Example:

```
kubectl cp herle-deployment-pod-5757d89d85-wrpc9:/tmp/application_heap_dump.bin /Users/amritharajherle/Desktop/application_heap_dump.bin
```

5. Use any memory leak analysis tool. I'm using the Eclipse's **Memory Analyzer** plugin.

- Open the heap dump file

[image: Open the heap dump file]

- select leak suspect report

[image: select leak suspects report]

- You can check the number of objects and retained heap space. Also some possible leak suspects.

Comment: i am getting below error
"jmap": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown command terminated with exit code 126.

Comment: A side note: better to run jmap without "live" to prevent GC from running before heap dump

Comment: kill -3 JAVA_PID Note the process ID number of the Java process (e.g. using top, a grep on ps -axw, etc.) and send a QUIT signal to the process with the kill -QUIT or kill -3 command 1. For example:

Comment: jmap does not exist in adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-slim java image, however it mostly likey jcmd would be there

use this command 

jcmd 2960 GC.heap_dump c:/temp/heapdump.hprof

Comment: Please remove `/tmp` from example you provided in p.4. or add `/tmp` in p.3

Comment: Getting jmap not found error. Using the jdk.  openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 21.10-(Zulu-11.52+13-linux-musl-x64)-Microsoft-Azure-restricted (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 21.10-(Zulu-11.52+13-linux-musl-x64)-Microsoft-Azure-restricted (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: @VineethNG if you don't have jmap present in the image then you can use either ephemeral containers or something like robusta.dev (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer). See https://home.robusta.dev/java for the latter